# How to apply formula to a cell dependent on data from drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I hope I can word this to where it makes sense. I'm working on a budget. Basically broken down by month. So in the budget, if it is February, I have to estimate the remaining months of the year. I have a formula that does that. My budget pulls in data from an external spreadsheet and this is done on a monthly basis. I have a drop down at the top of my workbook that allows a user to select the current month. So if February is selected in the drop down, I need to apply a formula to apply the actual numbers to the February cell instead of estimating. I'm just not sure how to do that. Again, I hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an if statement =if(A1="February",B1,B1*30/day(today()).  If it is February use the value in B1 if not Forecast it forward for a 30 day month by multiplying 30 divided by the current day of the month

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. It worked very well!

Comment: I dont see how to accept your comment as an answer though. Am I missing something?

Comment: No your not missing something.  As I put it as a comment it can't be accepted as an answer.  As you've copied it into an answer I will just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement =if(A1="February",B1,B1*30/day(today()). If it is February use the value in B1 if not Forecast it forward for a 30 day month by multiplying 30 divided by the current day of the month